# How to update, rotate and display a ply file with python?

Tags: python, 3d, pyopengl, ply-file-format, open3d

I tried using open3d, simpleRender and several other examples from the web but it was not good. SimpleRender is bugged and I can't start the python script at all. Open3d works but it has limited functionality. I am not able to display the ply file exactly as I want with open3d.

I have a stereo vision camera that generates new ply files every second. I need to display, rotate and update a ply file in a loop without closing the display window.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this:

- convert your ply files to octree using [PotreeConverter](https://github.com/potree/PotreeConverter)
- Then you can use it's CLI in python using a subprocess.

It generates a HTML file that can be rendered.

Comment: I need something that will load and display the ply file in the same python script that is running stereo vision cameras. PotreeConverter is in c++